# How to filter pojo class and make new pojo class from them

Tags: java, android, pojo

I have one POJO class .**ContactPOJO.class**

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private  int id;
    private  String contact_id;
    private  String contact_name;
    private  String contact_number;
    private  boolean is_selected;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContact_id() {
        return contact_id;
    }

    public void setContact_id(String contact_id) {
        this.contact_id = contact_id;
    }


    public boolean isIs_selected() {
        return is_selected;
    }

    public void setIs_selected(boolean is_selected) {
        this.is_selected = is_selected;
    }

    public String getContact_name() {
        return contact_name;
    }

    public void setContact_name(String contact_name) {
        this.contact_name = contact_name;
    }

    public String getContact_number() {
        return contact_number;
    }

    public void setContact_number(String contact_number) {
        this.contact_number = contact_number;
    }
```

Now I have to make new POJO class but only for that which  is_selected boolean value is true in ContactPOJO. I don't know how to do that . Any help would be appreciate.Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I have **`List<ContactPOJO> list_contact`**  . Which contains all contacts from phone . Now some of them will be selected ,some of them will be not .  its selected or not will be stored in is_selected variable . now I have to make new list .lets say **`List<newContactPOJO>`** . but it will contain only is_selected true value from that old one.

Comment: you want to make dynamic pojo class ?? thats not possible dude :)

Comment: please explain in brief :)

Comment: Make `NewPojo` class `extends` `ContactPOJO` => then override the setter of `is_selected`

Comment: What you ask ? i am not sure . But if you want to filer all selected instance from a list of ContactPOJO then just use a forEach loop, and add all selected elements in anther list .

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati i have updated my question . have a look at edit section

Comment: @TuyenNguyen thank you for your answer . but can you explain it more .

Comment: you get isSelected value from contacts right ??

Comment: i can get is_selected value from contact but i have to make new POJO for if is_selected value is true .@SubhashPrajapati

Comment: you can do this thing by logic bro you no need to make new Pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<ContactPOJO> list_contact;
List<ContactPOJO> list_selected_contact = new ArrayList();
for (ContactPOJO pojo : list_contact){
    pojo.setIs_selected(true);
    list_selected_contact.add(pojo);
}
```

==> now you have a new list with all selected object

Comment: I think . it should like `for (ContactPOJO pojo : list_contact){
    if(pojo.isIs_selected());
    list_selected_contact.add(pojo);
}`

Am I right ?

Comment: I don't know, I am not really understand what are your intent to do, so it depend on your demand